# How to update/publish/deploy a changing 'constant' part of a web page?

Tags: html, azure, asp.net-core

Got an Azure Web App (Asp.Net Core) including a page with a FAQ section. What is the best policy in effort and performance to get this section updated when the FAQ changes? Something like:

```
<div id="faq"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#faq').load('/faq/faq.html');
    });
</script>
```

or is there a better way? Thanks for any help!

Comment: This depends on your scenario. What is your issue with current implementation?

Comment: Agree. What are you looking to improve?

Comment: Is what we do common practice or is there a better way? Load html in html looks odd.